# How can I connect and disconnect from a proxy?

Tags: c#, server, proxy

I purchased a premium proxy and they only sent me an IP (51.38.119.210) and a username and password. I need this proxy in a C# project. I need a single-line method that connects me and a method that disconnect.

I googled everywhere and found these codes:

`WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("51.38.119.210");`
`WebProxy proxy = (WebProxy)WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();`

Comment: "I need this proxy in a C# project." Fantastic, and you tagged this with "Python" just by mistake, I assume. This mistake seems to be increasing :/

Comment: @roganjosh Mixing up python and proxy can happen. Plus it might be a python based Proxy server, I guess.

Comment: I can rewrite the whole project in Python.

Comment: @Christopher my experience suggests that it's just for people to try get more views... and it never ends how they expect

Comment: @EbiMeri: If you are more familiar with Python and Python is a allowed project format for the environment, go for it. Proxies with Logins are not a thing you see that often outside of company networks.

Comment: @Christopher I live in Iran and many important sites (like Facebook, Youtube, Twitter, Blogspot) are censored. I really need this API.

Comment: @roganjosh Please don't ridicule me. I am a novice.

Comment: @EbiMeri Then you put this in the Windows Settings for proxies: https://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-10/how-to-set-up-a-proxy-in-windows-10/ This interface has been around since 95 or so (but it used to be a per-interface setting IIRC). Firefox and other Mozilla products can be a bit special in that it ignores the Windows Proxy Settings (and Certificate Cache, for that mater). So those usually need manual setup in the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never actually gotten to use Proxies that much in practice, so my knowledge is mostly from Networking Theory.

But I guess it does something like NAT with PortForwarding: Requests reaching it on a Interface and Port Y, always get routed to Interface and Port X (of course the Interface but not the port could be the same). So it is all about setting the Server up with the proper fowarding (or whatever it is called for proxy severs). And then send to it's incomming Port.

Wich is unfortunately a mater of Network/Server Administration and not programming. This also sounds a lot like a homework assignment. For those we do not provide code, only directions.